# How to check how many keywords are in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check how many keywords in sentence

## Examples

1. keywords: `usually`, `drink`
2. sentence: What do you usually eat?
3. result: This contains 1 keywords, `usually`

## Examples2

1. keywords: `usually`, `drink`
2. sentence: What do you usually drink?
3. result: This contains 2 keywords, `usually` and `drink`

## Examples3

1. keywords: `if`, `fly`, `where`, `go`
2. sentence: If you could travel anywhere, where would you go?
3. result: This contains 3 keywords, `if`, `where` and `go`

I know regex, but I do not know how to use it. I look forward to your precious reply.

Comment: No precious reply from me.  We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: The simplest way would be to create an array of your keywords, looping over them, and adding to a counter when your input string contains the current element in the loop

Comment: Guys **dont** answer him! He needs to learn to put work into that himself, otherwise he will always come back and asks us such questions...

Comment: @L.Guthardt I agree, but instead of telling us, tell him (or her) how they should change their question, for example by linking to the [mcve] help page.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Agreed, will link that in the future.

Comment: @L.Guthardt easiest way to do that is writing `[ mcve ]` (no spaces)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Wow, thank you. I never knew that. Thats quite convient to be honest,

Comment: First solve the problem of looking for one keyword to see if it is present, then expand it to look for each of them, in turn, and count how many are present.

Comment: *"I know regex, but I do not know how to use it."* And I'm a pilot, I just don't know how to fly a plane.

Comment: Hint: `int count = keyWords.Count(sentence.Contains)`

Comment: `sentence.Split(' ', '.', ',', '!', '?').Intersect(keywords, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Count()`

Comment: What is your expectation on sub-word matches like `keyword = any` and `sentence = This could be anywhere` - should the result be 0 (no match) or 1 (__any__-where)

Answer (score 1):

1. Regex is a pattern that is matched against a string.
2. Regex pattern is matched against any occurrence in the string.
3. this pattern can be a lot of things like "All numbers", "start with Capital letter, and then all lowercase" and many more.
4. you should learn the Regex language, You can start [Here](https://regexone.com/) or [Here](https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/)
5. The Operator you are looking for is pipe `|` as in `(this|if|key|<keyword>)`
6. You can test regex expressions online @ [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Simple Regex in C#

```
Regex rx = new Regex("<my_pattern>");
var matches = rx.Matches("<my_string>");
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
 // do whatever you like here with the match.
}
```

**Note:** There are other ways to find multiple keywords in a string, which are faster, but i believe regex is the simplest one, and for a beginner, the best fit.

Comment: Even though it is a HW Question, i guess there is a place to give a student a nudge in the proper direction.

Comment: _"i believe regex is the simplest one, and for a beginner, the best fit."_ I disagree. `int count = keyWords.Count(sentence.Contains)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter Gotta admit it is a sleek query :). I was sure he wanted the actual keywords...

Answer (score 1):

Well, try solving the problem *step after step*:

Split the initial sentence into words. If we declare word to be a *substring of alpha characters* we can use `Regex`:

```
  string sentence = "What do you usually drink?";

  //TODO: what if word can include an apostroph, e.g. "its'"?
  var words = Regex
    .Matches(sentence, @"\w+")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value);

  // Check yourself: 
  // Console.Write(string.Join(", ", words));
```

Organize the `keywords`; let them be *case-insensitive*:

```
  HashSet<string> keywords = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "usually",
    "drink",
  };

  // Check yourself:
  // Console.WriteLine((keywords.Contains("Drink") ? "keyword" : "plain word"))
```

Filter out keywords from `words`:

```
  var result = words
    .Where(word => keywords.Contains(word))
    .ToArray();
```

Print out the `result`:

```
  Console.WriteLine(
    $"\"{sentence}\" contains {result.Length} keywords: [{string.Join(", ", result)}]");
```

Outcome:

```
"What do you usually drink?" contains 2 keywords: [usually, drink]
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I solved!!! really really thank you